# Atiyah-Macdonald Question 1.7

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, solution-verification

I have a solution to this question which I know to be wrong, but I can't find the mistake! The question reads "Let $A$ be a ring in which every element $x$ satisfies $x^n = x$ for some $n>1$. Show that every prime ideal in $A$ is maximal."

My solution goes:

We have $x^n-x = 0 \implies x(x^{n-1}-1) = 0$ so either $x$ is nilpotent or a unit or 0. If $x$ is nilpotent then so is $x^{n-1}$ as the nilradical is an ideal and so by Question 1 we have $x^{n-1}-1$ is a unit in $A$. Thus
$$0 = x(x^{n-1}-1)(x^{n-1}-1)^{-1} = x.$$
 Hence every non-zero element of $A$ is a unit and then the only prime and maximal ideal is (0).

I can't see where I've made the mistake but I must have somewhere otherwise it implies that all Boolean rings have two elements.

Comment: $A$ is not a domain of integrity, so $x(x^{n-1}-1)=0$ does not imply necessarily that $x$ is zero, a unit or nihilpotent, as both the factors could be different from $0$.

Comment: **Hint** $ $ Reduce to the domain case by [factoring out by a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3716/242). See the Linked questions list there for many more examples of this basic method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have $x^n-x = 0 \implies x(x^{n-1}-1) = 0$ so either $x$ is nilpotent or a unit or 0.

There are two mistakes in one here.  It appears you think that you are able to conclude that $x=0$ or $x^{n-1}-1=0$ from this line.

Firstly, as mentioned in a comment, this does not have to be an integral domain, and it need not be true.

Secondly, $x^{n-1}-1=0$ does not imply $x$ is nilpotent, it implies $x$ is a unit.

But basically the reasoning you gave is relevant, because you should be applying all this reasoning to $R/P$ where $P$ is a prime ideal. That proves that $R/P$ is a field, therefore $P$ is maximal.

Comment: The duplicate-hub for the main question seems to be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210940/29335), although since you successfully phrased your question as a "I know this is wrong but can't see the mistake" question, I'm inclined not to classify it as a duplicate. But just in case, make sure you search thoroughly first, in the future. Reading the duplicate solutions might have made you realize your mistake, and that would have been a better learning outcome for you.