# If $R$ is a ring such that $\forall x\in R, x^n=x$ for some $n>1$ then when $P$ is prime, why is $R/P$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, ideals, integral-domain

I was recently reading a post on MSE which had an argument like:

> If $P$ is a prime ideal of a ring $R$ all of whose elements satisfy $x^n = x$, then $R/P$ is an integral domain with the same property.  This implies that $R/P$ is a finite integral domain, hence a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.  Hence all prime ideals of $R$ are maximal (so $R$ is zero-dimensional).

Incidentally, I was trying to prove that : If $R$ is a ring such that $\forall x\in R, x^n=x$ for some $n>1$ then, every prime ideal is a maximal ideal.

However, I just don't get how can $R/P$ is finite?

Comment: The "incidentally" paragraph is addressed well [on the site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210940/29335).  I'm going to adjust the title so it reflects your actual question, instead of the one that fools people into thinking this is a duplicate.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks! I searched for this question previously on this site, but was unable to find it. Are you using any "search software"?

Comment: I usually use a tag and very relevant keywords, and that works 90% of the time.  Failing that, I try google with `site:math.stackexchange.com` specified

Comment: @rschwieb Ok, say, what did you try for this question? I have a request: Can you please take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829900/let-r-be-a-ring-and-p-be-an-ideal-containing-an-ideal-i-of-r-show-that ?  It's also about ideals. I am having a hard time solving it.

Comment: It would have been something like `[ring-theory] "prime ideal" maximal`, and then I recall I found something linked as a duplicate to the one I linked here.

Comment: As for the question you linked, I think you should follow the first comment and use [the third isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_C_(rings)) which makes it very straightforward.  It doesn't have anything to do with commutativity: the ideals between $R$ and $I$ and those of $R/I$ correspond in a way that respects order, so if $I\subseteq M\subseteq R$, then $M$ is maximal in $R$ iff it is maximal in $R/I$.

Comment: I suppose the first commenter erred in saying "field" where they should have said "simple ring."

Comment: @rschwieb Can you say what a simple ring is? Never have I heard about it.

Comment: [LMWTFY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring) In general, a "simple object" is something that doesn't have nontrivial kernels of morphisms. It's the same idea as "simple group" or "simple module."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every element of $R/P$ is a root of $x^n-x$. But over an integral domain, nonzero polynomials have only finitely many roots.

In the comments, a variant of the question was raised.
Suppose that we have the weaker condition that for all $x \in R$, there is some $n \in \Bbb N,n \geq 2$ (depending on $x$) such that $x^n=x$. Then we can still show that all prime ideals in $R$ are maximal, but $R/P$ might not be finite for all prime ideals $P$.

To see that $R/P$ is a field assuming that condition, we can choose $x \in R/P$ non-zero. Then we get $x^n=x$ for some $n\geq 2$. Because $R/P$ is a domain, we may cancel $x$ and get $x^{n-1}=1$. This implies that $x$ is a unit, because $1=xx^{n-2}$.

To see that $R/P$ might not be finite, consider $R=\overline{\Bbb F_p}$ (the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p$) and $P=0$. Here every element satisfies $x^{p^k}=x$ for some $k\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Can we precisely say:  If $R$ is an integral domain and $f:R\to R$ such that $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with $$a_n,a_{n-1},...,a_0\in R$$, then $f$ has at most $n$ roots ?

Comment: @ThomasFinley yes!

Comment: Thanks a ton for the confirmation!

Comment: But if $n$ is not a fixed value then?

Comment: @ThomasFinley if $n$ is not fixed, then $R/P$ is still a field, but might not be a finite field.

Comment: Is that a theorem? Or a result? If so, I wanna know the formal statement.

Comment: @ThomasFinley see the edit.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. The answer seems  to be fully complete imho.