# Let $R$ be a ring and $P$ be an ideal containing an ideal $I$ of $R.$ Show that $P$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ iff $P/I$ is a maximal ideal of $R/I.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $P$ be an ideal containing an ideal $I$ of $R.$ Show that $P$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ iff $P/I$ is a maximal ideal of $R/I.$

My attempt so far is as follows:

Let $P/I$ be a maximal ideal of $R/I$ then, let $U$ be a ideal of $R$ such that $P\subseteq U\subseteq R.$

This means, $P/I\subseteq U/I\subseteq R/I.$ We have two cases:

- If $P/I=U/I$ then, let $u\in U.$ This means $\exists p\in P$ such that $$p+I=u+I\implies u-p\in I\subseteq P\implies u\in P\implies U\subseteq P\implies U=P.$$
- If $U/I=R/I$ then, let $r\in R$. Thus, $\exists u\in U$ such that $$u+I=r+I\implies r-u\in I\implies r-u\in P\subseteq U\implies r-u\in U\implies r\in U\implies R\subseteq U\implies U=R.$$

Thus, $P$ is a maximal ideal.

Next, we assume that $P$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ and try to prove that, $P/I$ is a maximal ideal of $R/I.$

---

This is the portion precisely, where I am stuck. Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These kind of questions are more workable using abstract properties of quotients, even though it takes some getting used to. Hint: $R/P\cong (R/I)/(P/I)$ and an ideal is maximal iff the corresponding quotient is a field.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos  "an ideal is maximal iff the corresponding quotient is a field" - is true only if R is a commutative ring with identity. Can you please elaborate your approach? I am not quite getting it.

Comment: I'm used to the convention that "ring" includes "commutative with identity". I haven't had much to do with non-commutative rings, so I don't know if a similar approach works there.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Oh! ok, no problem. Thank you!

Comment: There's a version for non-commutative rings where you replace "field" with a "simple module". Another way is to use the ideal correspondance theorem and that respects set containment.

Comment: In particular, let $\pi: R \to R/I$ be the natural projection and $J$ an ideal lying between $P/I$ and $R/I$, then $\pi^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal between $P$ and $R$.

Comment: @NaweedG.Seldon Can you please enlighten me about the full version of the ideal cirrespondence theorem?

Comment: I have added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Useful for this question is the ideal correspondence theorem, which states that there's an order-preserving bijection between ideals of $R/I$ and ideals of $R$ containing $I$. The order here is set containment. Let $\pi: R \to R/I$ be the natural projection, the map
\begin{align*}
\Phi:\{U \subseteq R\ :\ \text{$U$ an ideal such that $I \subseteq U \subseteq R$}\} &\longrightarrow \{J \subseteq R/I\ :\ \text{$J$ an ideal}\}\\
U &\longmapsto U/I 
\end{align*}
is a bijection with inverse
\begin{align*}
\Psi: \{J \subseteq R/I\ :\ \text{$J$ an ideal}\} &\longrightarrow \{U \subseteq R\ :\ \text{$U$ an ideal such that $I \subseteq U \subseteq R$}\}\\
J &\longmapsto \pi^{-1}(J) 
\end{align*}
In particular, $U \subseteq V \subseteq R$ if and only if $\Phi(U) \subseteq \Phi(V) \subseteq R/I$.