# A number theory trivia.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb N_{>1}$ and $a\neq c$.

Does having both $ab=cd$, $gcd(a,c)=1$, $a\geq d$ and $c\geq b$ imply that $a=d$ and $b=c$ holds?

Comment: $5\cdot 6=3\cdot 10$ so ....

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is $a=1$, $b=c=d=0$.  However, there are no counterexamples if you require $b\neq 0$.  Since $a$ and $c$ are relatively prime but $c$ divides $ab$, $c$ must divide $b$.  Since $b\neq 0$ and $c\geq b$, this can only happen if $b=c$.  It then follows that $a=d$.

Comment: don't think $gcd(a,c)$ is defined for $ac=0$ case. Also $0\not\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: It's quite standard to say $\gcd(0,n)=n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  See the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386651/is-this-gcd0-0-0-a-wrong-belief-in-mathematics-or-it-is-true-by-conventi for why this makes sense.

Comment: ok still $0\not\in\Bbb N$.