# Why $\gcd(0,0)=0$ when $0/0$ is undefined?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is this only a standard we have to follow? But Doesn't such acceptance manifests into a wrong solution eventually for some problem? If no, is there any proof?

Comment: Related, [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495119/what-is-gcd0-0) [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386651/is-this-gcd0-0-0-a-wrong-belief-in-mathematics-or-it-is-true-by-conventi).

Comment: I wonder how you people can find duplicates so quickly! 

Comment: They probably typed "gcd(0,0)" in the search  bar up right. Or on google.