# What is $0$ in the concept of prime and composite integers?

Tags: prime-numbers

All numbers could be prime or composite except $1$. But what about $0$, is it prime or composite?

Comment: Looking at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) it seems composite is a definition for positive integers. It says "A composite number is a positive integer that can be formed by multiplying two smaller positive integers.". I guess under this definition $0$ is not a composite number (since it isn't a positive integer), moreover it is clear which of the positive integers are composite :)

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535010/why-is-zero-not-composite

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698/why-doesnt-0-being-a-prime-ideal-in-mathbb-z-imply-that-0-is-a-prime-num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, prime and composite numbers are defined *only* on the set of natural numbers greater than $1$. Since, 0 is not a natural number it isn't even eligible for classification as prime or composite.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I believe that most modern treatments actually consider 0 to be a natural number.

Comment: But that doesn't matter because you need to exclude $1$ anyway, and everyone (for the last several hundred years) agrees _that_ is a natural number.

Comment: @Troposphere you're right. But the fact, that even I missed in my answer, is that prime and composite numbers are defined only on natural numbers > 1. So, I've now made the necessary edit. But, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

A number is prime when it can only be divided by $1$ and itself but we choose to exclude $1$ as a prime because the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic would fail to produce a unique decomposition if we included it. For example $6$ uniquely decomposes as $2 \cdot 3$ but if we allowed $1$ then it could be decomposed as $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$ or $1^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$ which would give two distinct decompositions breaking uniqueness. Since $0 = 0^2$ it would also break uniqueness of the decomposition so it is excluded as a prime. Since a composite number has more than one prime in its decomposition $0$ is also not composite.

Comment: Also, $0=0\cdot2, 0=0\cdot3$, etc, make the non-uniqueness issue even worse.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot even be classified in your traditional prime/composite classification because it does not have a unique decomposition that, say, 211311 has. This is why the traditional prime/composite numbers extend only to positive integers.