# What does “factor out” an ideal mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am studying [this article](https://sci-hub.tw/https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/plms/s3-42.3.559). In proving Theorem 2.14—

> Let $R$ be an $\alpha$-ring and $S=R[x,\alpha]$. Then $S$ is $\alpha$-Jacobson if and only if $R$ is $\alpha$-Jacobson

—the author says that:

> . . . we can factor out $(P \cap R)S $, which is contained in $P$, and assume that $P \cap R = 0$

(where $P$ is an $\alpha$-prime ideal of $S$).

I don't understand what this “factor out” means. Any help would be great.

Comment: See [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3716/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque, I read your answer. I didn't understand the following : "For example, in many ring theoretic problems involving an ideal I, one can reduce to the case I=P prime, then reduce to R/P, **thus reducing to the case when the ring is a domain**."  How can we reduce to the case when R is a domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means to consider the quotient. When you do $P/(P\cap R)$, now $P\cap R$ is the zero of the quotient.

Comment: I edited the question, its $(P \cap R)S$ rather than $P \cap R$. I read what Bill commented but I still don't see why we can only considerer the case $P \cap R = 0$. In another article, the author justifies by the isormophism $S/(P \cap R)S \cong R/(P \cap R) [x,\alpha]$, but I still don't see it. Can you explain more, please?