# Question about the zero ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have been studying Ring theory and a question came up.

Theorem: A commutative ring $R$ is integral domain iff the zero ideal $I=\{0\}$ is prime ideal in $R$.

***Question:*** How can it be that in $\mathbb{Z}$ we do not count $I=\{0\}$ as a prime ideal ?(That's what is stated in my book)

We know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is integral domain. So the zero ideal must be prime.

Comment: $(0)$ is a prime ideal in $\Bbb Z$, if $ab\in (0)$ then either $a\in (0)$ or $b\in (0)$.

Comment: Can you show us _exactly_ what your book states?

Comment: The zero ideal is a prime one iff the (non-trivial) ring is an integral domain. If it is stated otherwise in your book or anywhere then that is wrong

Comment: See [Why doesn't $0$ being a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z$ imply that $0$ is a prime number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3698/242). If this is really what you are asking about then we can close as a dupe of that (and likely many others).

Answer (score 2):

An ideal is prime if  whenever it contains a product it  contains one of the factors. The zero ideal has that property just for integral domains.

Comment: So the zero ideal is prime in the integers.

Comment: $I=0$ is a prime ideal iff $\Bbb{Z}/I=\Bbb{Z}$ is an integral domain. So yes.