# Basic maths question

Tags: arithmetic

If I have 25 apples and multiply them zero times, why is it that I end up with zero? I understand zero times means no times, right? I mean, multiply by zero is no multiplication. Can anyone explain, please?

Comment: $25\times m$ means $m$ lots of $25$. So $25\times 0$ would mean $0$ lots of $25$, i.e. nothing.

Comment: Masic baths question?

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20091/is-there-any-physical-analogy-to-explain-multiplication-by-zero. And many other similar questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+multiplication+by+zero

Comment: What do you get if you have $25$ apples and multiply them two times?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if we use some "powerfull" definitions in math, we may remember that the set of Integers number (a.k.a. "$\Bbb{Z}$") is an ***abelian grup*** (if you want to know more about this, I recommend to start with basic ring theory; you may find a good resume [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics))). Rings are more "complete" in some sense that groups, but, in my opinion, is easier to have some touch with then before.

So, doesn't matter if you multiply $a \times b$ or $b \times a$. Although it looks a rule to everything, there are others *groups*, *rings*, etc. which this isn't true (e.g. the Matrix multiplications). So in this case, what you may think is:

$0$ times $25$ is the same as $25$ times $0$. So,

$$
0 + 0+ \dots + 0 = 0.
$$
(Trust me, there are $25$ $0$'s in the *dots*).

The $0$ itself is something complicated in math and is a object of trouble since ever, just look at division, for example. So, I hope you've understanded and, otherwise, just get in touch!

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a simple way. We know multiplication is just repeated addition. Then,

$$ 25\cdot0 = \underbrace{0+0+\dots + 0}_{25\text{ zeroes}} = 0 $$

In an apple context, this means trying to add up an amount of zero apples. You won't get any apples, because there aren't any apples to add up.