# How can an irreducible polynomial be represented as a product of irreducible polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

In Charles Pinter's *Abstract Algebra*, he presents the factorization theorem for polynomials. That is,

> Every polynomial $a(x)$ of positive degree in $F[x]$ can be written as a product
> \begin{equation*}
> a( x) =kp_{1}( x) p_{2}( x) \cdots p_{r}( x)
> \end{equation*}
> where $k$ is a constant and $p_1(x),...,p_r(x)$ are monic irreducible polynomials of $F[x]$.

But I am confused by the next paragraph,

> If this were not true, we could choose a polynomial $a(x)$ of lowest degree among those which cannot be factored into irreducibles. Then $a(x)$ is reducible, so $a(x)=b(x)c(x)$ where $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ have lower degree than $a(x)$. But this means that $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ can be factored into irreducibles, and therefore $a(x)$ can also.

My issue is if we choose a polynomial $a(x)$ *among those which **cannot** be factored into irreducibles* then how is $a(x)$ reducible? We just said choose one that *isn't* reducible. Moreover, I don't understand how we immediately know that $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ are reducible as well. All we said was that they were of lower degree, not that they were reducible.

This leads to the more general question, how can ***every*** polynomial of positive degree be factored into irreducibles? For example, take any one of these irreducible factors $p_r(x)$, by definition, $p_r(x)$ *cannot* be written as a product of irreducibles since this would mean that it *is* reducible and thus couldn't be an irreducible factor of $a(x)$. It seems to me that we are saying that even irreducible polynomials can be written as a product of irreducibles. I can't seem to locate where my misunderstanding is.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with the theorem as stated. If $F$ is $\Bbb{Z}$, $x^2 - 2$ is irreducible and surely can't be written as a product of *monic* polynomials in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. So the theorem would not hold, unless I'm missing some context. The same happens in $\Bbb{R}[x]$ with $x^2 + 2$. Is $F$ an algebraically closed field?

Comment: @NikiDiGiano Sorry, I should have specified. Pinter uses $F$ to specifically represent a **field**. So in this case, $F \neq \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: Here, an irreducible is considered to be a "product" of irreducibles (a product of elements from a set containing only one element). Such singleton (and empty) products often prove handing for induction & recursion. This is explained at length in the  analogous proof for *integers* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3543271/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: Note also that the proof is clearer when presented in non-contradiction form as in the linked dupe.

Comment: ^^^ typo: "handing" -> "handy"

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, that proof is much more clear and elaborate. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

The point you need to understand is that factoring a polynomial into a product of a single term is allowed. Indeed, this is the only option for irreducible monic polynomials.

In this way, if $a(x)$ were irreducible, then writing $a(x)$ would be a product of irreducible factors (which is assumed not to exist), so $a(x)$ must be reducible. As for $b(x)$ and $c(x)$, they are not necessarily reducible, and could just be a product each of one term.

Comment: But this sounds like every polynomial is reducible then. What constitutes an irreducible polynomial if we can always find some product to represent it?

Comment: An irreducible polynomial cannot be written as a product of **two** polynomials **of lesser degree**. This includes the $3$ or more case as well. All polynomials, reducible or not, can be written trivially as a product of one polynomial.