# 3 different prime ideals in Z[x]

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

> find 3 different prime ideals in $Z[x]$, $I,J,K$ such that $I\subset J\subset K$.

have no clue where to start from.

Comment: Do you know any examples of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Can you find a chain of two ideals?

Comment: What is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Comment: for example $0\subseteq(2)\subseteq(2,x)$

Comment: Is there a chain of *four* prime ideals?

Comment: @Qiaochu: guess not, i'm new to this material..

Comment: @jspecter, I meant that question as food for thought for the OP.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint 1.** Since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an integral domain, there is a very small prime ideal (in fact, it has as few elements as any ideal has any right to have).

**Hint 2.** [There is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54951/242) a one-to-one, inclusion preserving correspondence between the ideals of $R/I$ and the ideals of $R$ that contain $I$. This correspondence preserves primality. So, perhaps you can find some proper prime ideal $P$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/P$ (which must be an integral domain) has a proper prime ideal as well? Then you could "lift" it back to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and that would give you your $J$ and $K$. Then use the first hint for your $I$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\ $ [Factoring out a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120/is-1-a-prime-number/5735#5735) $\rm\:p \ne 0\:$ reduces it to finding a chain of two prime ideals in $\rm\:\mathbb F_p[x]\:.$

A similar reduction tackles lhf's question in the comments - see Theorem 37 below from Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings.* (Theorem 34 is the bijective order-preserving correspondence between prime ideals in a localization $\rm\:R_S\:$ and all prime ideal in $\rm\:R\:$ disjoint from $\rm\:S\:$).

[image]