# Primality of number 1

Tags: prime-numbers, number-theory

Is number 1 prime as per the definition of prime numbers? Because as per the definition for being prime it should be divided only by 1 and number itself.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/59076/589.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number 1 is not a prime because it is defined that way. It is really important because if 1 was a prime number, there would be no unicity of an integer decomposition into prime number factors.

Answer (score 5):

As in @Thekwasti's comment, the "question" of whether $1$ is a prime or not has no genuine mathematical content, but is only a question of convention. Indeed, for a long time it was considered a prime "by definition", and the assertions about unique factorization were all the more clumsy because of that. Thus, historically, there was a collective ... probably not overt... decision to declare $1$ *not* prime, to make the statements of the well-known theorems cleaner.

The decisive perspective on the issue is that our collective choice of terminology does not change the underlying reality.

Answer (score 4):

No. For a number to be prime, it must have exactly *two* divisors. $1$ has only *one* divisor.

It's important for $1$ not to be a prime, because one of the most important theorems about prime numbers is this:

*Every number can be written as the product of prime numbers in only one way (not counting different orders).*

Examples: $15=3\times5$, and that is the *only* way to write $15$ as the product of primes.
$150=2\times3\times5\times5$, and that is the *only* way to write $150$ as the product of primes.

This wouldn't be true if $1$ were a prime. If it were, then $15$ could be written as $3\times5$, $1\times3\times5$, $1\times1\times3\times5$, etc.

This means that, if "prime" were defined in such a way to include $1$, then the primes would be a lot less useful. Therefore, we exclude $1$ from the primes.

Answer (score 2):

I am so old I was taught that definition, that it's enough for a prime number to be divisible only by $1$ and itself. But my children and grandchildren were taught that a prime number must have exactly two distinct divisors among the positive integers. When I first heard about this redefinition, I thought it made sense.

Because, you see, there were some things that bothered me about $1$ being a prime number, some things that didn't quite make sense to me. For example, consider the sequence $p^n$ where $n$ runs over the positive integers. $p^n$ gets larger as $n$ gets larger. But $1^n = 1$ no matter what $n$ is. In this way, $1$ is different from the prime numbers. But it is also different from the composite numbers.

There is at least one property $1$ shares with *some* composite numbers: $\sqrt{1} \in \mathbb{Q}$. But $\sqrt[n]{1} = 1$ no matter what $n$ is. Compare a number like $4$, see that while $\sqrt{4} = 2$, $\sqrt[3]{4} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$.

As a schoolchild I wasn't able to express these misgivings I had about $1$ being a prime number. But it was clear to me that $1$ differs from the prime numbers in a much more fundamental way than $2$ differs from the odd primes.

Comment: Thank you! No hand-wringing over the FTA, just facts about 1.

Comment: Then again 1 satisfies several properties usually reserved for prime numbers, such as Wilson's theorem.

Comment: It's not that those properties are somehow "reserved" for the prime numbers. A number either satisfies a property or it doesn't. You can find a lot of properties satisfied by 1 and the prime numbers (see Sloane's A008578 for some of them). But you can also find lots of properties that 2 and the odd primes satisfy but 1 doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of a prime, a prime is divisible by 2 numbers: 1 AND itself. Because 1 is only divisible by 1 number, 1, 1 is not a prime.

Answer (score 0):

No, the number 1 is not a prime. Prime numbers are usually explicitly defined to be natural numbers larger than 1 so that the number is only divisible by 1 and the number it self.

Comment: But why the definition says about being divisible from the number 1 and the number itself?
Isn't this *definition* true for Number 1

Comment: My definition says "a positive integer $n$ is called *prime* if and only if it is divisible by exactly $2$ distinct positive integers". It is still a matter of definition, but for most (all that I'm aware of) applications, excluding $1$ makes sense. This also conforms nicely to generalizations of the concept of primality such as, for instance, in ring theory.

Comment: It is true that the number $1$ is only divisible by $1$ and it self. However, primes are usually defined explicitly not to be $1$. This is just a convention adopted in math. Why this is the definition used I can not say, it may mainly be for convenience. For example, prime factorizations would not be unique if $1$ was also included in the primes.

Comment: In earlier times $1$ was considered a prime number. But like the example for unique decomposition of integers into prime numbers it turned out, that in almost every theorem considering primes $1$ has to be excluded (like "Let $p$ be a prime but not $1$. Then ...). I guess this is one of the reasons the definition has changed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wikipedia article on prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_of_one):

> Most early Greeks did not even consider $1$ to be a number, and so
>   they did not consider it a prime. In the 19th century, however, many
>   mathematicians did consider the number $1$ a prime. For example,
>   Derrick Norman Lehmer's list of primes up to $10{,}006{,}721$,
>   reprinted as late as 1956, started with $1$ as its first prime. Henri
>   Lebesgue is said to be the last professional mathematician to call $1$
>   prime.

The point is, whether you consider $1$ to be a prime -- that is, whether you define "prime number" in such a way that $1$ meets the definition -- is merely a matter of convention.  The modern convention excludes it.  There seems to be general agreement (*vide* other answers here) that this is done to simplify various assertions involving primes, which would otherwise require the phrase "greater than $1$."  (Note, we do consign ourselves to utilizing the phrase "greater than $2$" or the adjective "odd" in quite a few settings where primes appear.)  The price we pay is putting that phrase in elementary statements such as  "Every number *greater than* $1$ is either prime or composite."

Answer (score 0):

Considering $1$ a prime muddies the notion of being coprime or relatively prime. Although $a$ and $b$ are coprime or relatively prime if $\gcd (a,b)=1$, this relationship is in fact derivative of the more basic notion (from which the words actually arise) that $a$ and $b$ are coprime or relatively prime when they have no common prime factors. If $1$ is a prime, that more basic notion of sharing no prime factors has to be forever after qualified with the explicit exception "other than $1$."